# How to Update value and ADD UP the previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to update a value in my query but I want to add up the previous value. For example, if I have the value of 10 stored and I want to update with 15, the new value should be 25. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = YourColumn+15
```

(Though I encourage you to use a filter on that `UPDATE`)

Answer (score 1):

You can update your table and set your column as itself + n where `n` is your new value to add

```
UPDATE table
SET columnname = columnname + n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET value = value+15;
GO
```